# Using d3 in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, d3.js

I want to load in and display different TSVs to the webpage, specific to the date pulled. I have four lowtemp fridges, each with the same 4 instruments on it. I want to show the most recent data for each fridge and each instrument.

Tried multiple instances of timeout to wait on d3. Doesn't seem to matter due to order of operations.

This is my HTML:

```
var instrumentArray = ["PT", "LAK", "OPT", "OPTall"];
//only using one for first draft coding.
var fridgeArray = ["BlueForce1"];

for (var i=0;i < fridgeArray.length; i+=1) { 
    for (var j=0;j<instrumentArray.length;j+=1) {
        console.log(i,j,fridgeArray[i],instrumentArray[j]); console.log("/Data/"+fridgeArray[i]+getInstrumentURL(instrumentArray[j]));


   d3.tsv("/Data/"+fridgeArray[i]+getInstrumentURL(instrumentArray[j]))
        .then(function(data) {                          
            show_inst_now(data,fridgeArray[i],instrumentArray[j]);      
            Loaded_Data[j]= data;
        });  
        setTimeout(console.log(timeout),3000);              
    };  
};
```

my JS:

```
function show_inst_now(data,fridge,inst)
    {
        console.log(inst, fridge);
    switch (`${inst}`){
        case "PT":
document.getElementById("Date  Time").innerHTML = "Last Data Grab: " + data[data.length-1]['Date  Time'];
document.getElementById("On Off").innerHTML = "On(1) Off(0) :  " + data[data.length-1]['Comp On'];
document.getElementById("Input Water temp (C)").innerHTML = "Input Water temp (C): " + data[data.length-1]['Input Water temp (C)'];
document.getElementById("Output water temp (C)").innerHTML = "Output Water temp (C): " + data[data.length-1]['Output water temp (C)'];
document.getElementById("Helium temp (C)").innerHTML = "Helium temp (C): " + data[data.length-1]['Helium temp (C)'];
document.getElementById("Oil temp (C)").innerHTML = "Oil temp (C): " + data[data.length-1]['Oil temp (C)'];
        case "LAK":

                        //  more of the same, different IDs...
        default : 
                  console.log("fail");
          }
```

The for-loop console.logs 4 times before getting to d3.

I've already tried putting in wait intervals to let d3 process asynchronously, but it doesn't seem to even go into d3 before it hits the timeout.

The console.logs in the JavaScript are saying undefined parameters are being passed to it, even though the console.logs are confirming what i want to pass to it in the HTML.

the for-loop is hitting d3 the amount of times that i want, just not in the programmed order.

***Console output:***

```
0 0 "BlueForce1" "PT"

/Data/BlueForce1/2019/Jul/2019.07.30.PT.txt

timeout

0 1 "BlueForce1" "LAK"

/Data/BlueForce1/2019/Jul/2019.07.30.LAK.txt

timeout

0 2 "BlueForce1" "OPT"

/Data/BlueForce1/2019/Jul/2019.07.30.OPT.txt

timeout

0 3 "BlueForce1" "OPTall"

/Data/BlueForce1/2019/Jul/2019.07.30.OPTall.txt

timeout

undefined undefined

fail

undefined undefined

fail

undefined undefined

fail

undefined undefined

fail
```

Comment: You sure "this is my HTML" is HTML? Looks a lot like more JS.

Comment: karfus, it may be JS but its whats in my HTML document.

Comment: the weird thing is that if I get rid of the switch in my linked JS, the data writes to the HTML just fine. even though console.log is showing parameters passed as undefined.

Comment: Even more review, only data gets passed, no matter the order of arguments. everything else is always passed as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue that I see is that you are running asynchronous code in a for loop.

`d3.tsv()` is asynchronous and returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

If a piece of code is asynchronous, that means that it *doesn't* block, but instead allows the next line(s) of code to execute. This is usually the case for requests that get data from the server and other scenarios where there could be a relatively long wait of an unknown length. Instead, what happens is a Promise is set up, that on a certain event (e.g. when the file is returned to the browser) it will execute a certain function (the *callback*) which is provided with the returned data.

In your code, `d3.tsv()` makes a request for the file, and sets up the callback function for the Promise to execute when the file is returned, and then gets on with the next iteration of the loop while it is waiting for the response.

*This part is fast*, so all the loops are executed before any of the responses are returned.

Once the responses are returned, the code in the *callbacks* execute `show_inst_now` and tries to access the `i` and `j` variables, which are either the last value in the loop by now, or undefined (I can't remember which).

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    d3.tsv('//mydata/from/a/slow/server.tsv')
        .then(function callbackExecutesWhenDataReturned() {
            console.log('in callback, iteration: ' + i);
        });
    console.log('in for loop, iteration: ' + i);
}
```

If the server is really slow returning the `server.tsv` data, then probably the console output will be:

```
in for loop, iteration: 1
in for loop, iteration: 2
in for loop, iteration: 3
in callback, iteration: 3 or undefined
in callback, iteration: 3 or undefined
in callback, iteration: 3 or undefined
```

One thing that you could do is use Promise.all() to wait for all your asynchronous requests to come back before you process then process the data:

```
Promise.all([
    d3.tsv('path/to/file1.tsv),
    d3.tsv('path/to/file2.tsv),
    d3.tsv('path/to/file3.tsv)
]).then(function processResponses(myArrayOfThreeResponses) {
    myArrayOfThreeResponses.forEach(function(response, index) {
        show_inst_now(response);
        Loaded_Data[index] = response;
    });
});
```

Would definitely recommend the [MDN Promise docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) again, and reading up on asychronous programming which is a big part of JavaScript that you'll use again and again.

Comment: I'm confused how the data in my d3 gets handled. Where are you handling data? d3.tsv needs a .then()

nesting thens doesnt seem to make JS happy.

Comment: @HAZRD If you look at the end of my post, you can see one solution to manage multiple requests and wait for all of them to return before handling the data in the callback (which is the argument to the `then()` method). You really need to understand how Promises work, otherwise you will continue to run into issues.

Comment: Yeah I still can't wrap my head around promise and async. Im justs going to parse my page into tabs and run d3 when the tab is launched.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to display this in a specific web page. If not, and you are just experimenting, I'd recommend looking at https://ObservableHQ.com. There's a really good example on how you can load tsv and csv data directly from GitHub Gist (https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/introduction-to-data). It handles the asynchronous request etc.